# assigning and changing data type during compile time ( c++ )

Tags: c++

okay this is just a wild idea.
Can you put variable type in a variable during compile time?

`type` contains `int`, and then you change it to `char`

And you decide to change it again!
`type`  contains class object.
just keep changing it

And it can be used like

```
type = int;
type var = 5; ( when type was assigned to int )
type = std::string
type var_2 = "hello" ( when type was assigned to std::string )
```

Comment: That's the concept for [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Is it? An `std::variant` is a single object that can be many types. This is talking about, like, saving the result of `decltype(foo)` into a variable.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to do. A variable's type is determined at compile time, so what is the idea you are looking for with your `type` "variable"?

Comment: Best answer is template programing. If you could provide details of your problem someone will give you a good example how to write template for your specific problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using macros.

```
#undef type
#define type int

type var = 5;

#undef type
#define type char

type var2 = 'a';
```

However, this will be extremely confusing, I strongly recommend against it.

Comment: Don't forget to `#undef type` again when you are done.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I assume it always undefs before deffing

Comment: yuck macros. Why not use template programing for that?

Comment: @MarekR Because this seems to be the closest match for the OP's use case.

Comment: @Barmar `#define` does not automatically `#undef`, and if you `#define` something twice with different values, you are likely to get a warning.  Plus, you don't always know if your `#define` will affect anything else down the line out of scope of what you intended to use it for, so best to `#undef` explicitly when you are done using the `#define`'d value.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's why I have explicit `#undef` before each `#define`. There's no point in doing the `#define` for just one variable, it obviously has to last until he wants to redefine it.

Comment: @Barmar “*explicit `#undef` before each `#define`*” - before, but I was talking about after. Don’t leave it `#define`’d for longer than absolutely necessary, `#under it as soon as possible.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It all depends on the use case. I interpreted the question as wanting it to be in effect until redefined.

Answer (score 1):

Syntactic errors aside, you may not use

```
type = int;
type = std::string;
```

in the same scope.

If you are willing to use different scopes, you may use:

```
{
   // One scope
   using type = int;
   type var = 5;
}

{
   // New scope
   using type = std::string;
   type var_2 = "hello";
}
```

**PS**

I don't recommend using type aliases for fundamental types and types in the standard library. It makes reading and understanding of code harder.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking - no.
Variables can't change their type.

There are different mechanics that are similar and solves problems like this.

1. Templates - they enable operation on unspecified data structures.
2. Conversion - pretty basic, instead of changing variable data type you are changing value data type.
3. Polymorphism - you can store multiple classes of the same type in single container, so let's say you have:

   > Class A;      Class B:A;      Class C:A;

   > ```
   >  std::list<A> listOfA;  B b;  C c;  listOfA.append(B);  listOfA.append(C);
   > ```

So you are sort of having multiple "types" in one variable.

Answer (score 0):

IMO best and most flexible way to approach this is use templates.
Macros are sloppy and to dangerous (have many disadvantages).

```cpp
template<typename T>
constexpr T defaultValue = T{};

template<>
constexpr int defaultValue<int> = 5;

template<>
const std::string defaultValue<std::string> = "hello";

...
    auto x = defaultValue<int>;
    auto s = defaultValue<std::string>;
    auto y = defaultValue<size_t>;
```

https://www.godbolt.org/z/f9vdMn